# Next number that is a 1 and zeroes

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

There's probably a much better way of expressing this, but I don't know it, so I guess that's part of the question too. I'm not even sure what to tag it.

How do I find the next number greater than a given number that is a 1 followed by zeroes.

For instance

- 12 => 100
- 9343 => 10,000

etc.

Thanks

Comment: 10,000 $\to$ $__$ ?

Comment: Oh good question. In this instance 10,000. What I'm trying to do is find a neat way of creating a unique integer from two numbers, e.g. 2222 and 33333 => 222233333; by knowing that 33333 goes to 100,000 then I can multiply the first number by 100,000 and simply add them.

Comment: Note that the formula in an answer below gives 100,000 in this case, not 10,000.

Comment: Thanks, in fact I _do_ need 10,000 => 100,000 for the scenario above to work!

Comment: Just make up your mind...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$10^{\lfloor log_{10}(x) \rfloor + 1}$$

Where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the floor function, i.e. the highest integer $n$ s.t. $n\leq x$

Comment: Thank you. But (unless I'm misreading this) then isn't it the result of the logarithm of x than needs to be floored, rather than x itself?

Comment: Yes, as shown at the top of my answer. Sorry, I should perhaps of chosen a different symbol when explaining what the floor function is, it's not the same $x$ as in the formula above.